# Combinations and permutations with constraints

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 6 people be seated around a table for 6, if 2 of the group  are always:

- together? - I solved this by doing 2! x 4!
- separate? - I do not know how to do this, the answer is 72

Can you plz explain the second part?

Comment: it does not have to be very detailed just write down ur calculations

Comment: its a round table, and yes just 2 need to be seated together, basically they need to be right next to each other

Comment: @Joffan pleasee i answered ur questions, may u plz help m e

Comment: Try finding all possible permutations, then subtracting the ones in which the two are sitting together. (You already found how many to subtract)

Comment: There are $5!=120$ arrangements with no restriction. There are  $48$ with our friends together, as you found, so the number of separated arrangements is $120-48=72$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the total arrangement minus the number of arrangements when the two persons sitting together to get the number of the separate arrangements. $5!-2!\times 4!$.

Answer (score 0):

There's always this tension between people when answering "round table" questions. Your solution of $2!4!$ for the first part suggests that you are in the camp that holds that the seat positions are indistinguishable. I would personally multiply your answer by $6$, as I have never experienced such a table.

However, in the spirit of your first answer,  I would say a similar process should be used. First arbitrarily seat the first person from your restricted pair, then chose one of the three seats not next to that person for other one. Then permute the other four less-fussy dining companions into the remaining four seats. Which is just $\frac 32$ times your other answer - whichever camp you are in.